# How to prevent CSS table row expanding to parent height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table with CSS `display:table` `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`. The problem is I can't set the height of table rows. They are expanded to parent height. In my code I set `.trow` height to `30px` but they are expanded to parent height `400px`.`!important` and inline style are not work too. How can I solve this?

P.S So sorry for my poor English.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table{
            display: table;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            height: 400px;
        }
        .trow{
            height: 30px;
            display: table-row;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #444444;
        }
        .tcell{
            display: table-cell;
            width: 20%;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table">
    <div class="trow" style="height: 30px">
        <div class="tcell">I'm table cell</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `display: table`, if you need non-table behaviour? Default table behaviour (if table height is specified) is to expand row heights until whole table height is filled. This is exactly what you get.

Just remove all `display` properties and evertything will be fine.

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yBUkr/)

Comment: Thanks. Now I remove all display properties and set `.tcell`'s `display:` properties to `inline-block`. It's work.

Answer (score 0):

this is the default behaviour of a table-cell.
if you want the cell not to fill the gap, you have to provide something else that will.

i just added another row:

```
<div class="trow tfill">
    <div class="tcell"></div>
</div>
```

that pushes your row to the top of the table

```
.tfill{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vdy4Y/